# BCP SQL Server Invalid Date Format

Tags: sql-server, csv, azure, azure-sql-database, bcp

I have a load of data to import into a Azure SQL database. The table I'm copying too has a time stamp field in smalldatetime format and then another 195 fields of floats. I'm trying to BCP a csv file into the table. The CSV file has the exact same format. The timestamps are identical in format but I keep getting an invalid date format error.

Example of TimeStamp from database:

```
2017-11-05 12:00:00
```

Example of TimeStamp from csv file:

```
2017-11-27 00:16:37
```

I have tried using bcp with -n and a format file generated with -n and a format file generated with -x. All give the invalid date format error.

```
bcp dbo.Meters format nul -n -S <URL> -d <databasename> -U <username> -P <password> -f format.fmt 

bcp dbo.Meters IN "output.csv" -S <URL> -d <databasename> -U <username> -P <password> -f format.fmt -t ,
```

I have also tried using the -c option and this gives a different error:

```
Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding.
```

I couldn't find much on google relating to this but it seems to mean there are fractions of seconds in the timestamps in the csv file which exceed the size of the smalldatetime format in the database table. None of the timestamps in the csv file have any fractional seconds though.

Does anyone know why it thinks the dates are in different formats? Thanks in advance!

Sample of CSV file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yTt2DgSROsP-6jMwrdQJxD7RE5EnhSiy/view?usp=sharing).

Create table statement with different field names can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lna7pWDnShtblPHzUc75AK6a7qIGDnEx/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: I'd advice you to try and isolate the problem. Make a test against a table with only the smalldatetime field and a csv file with only a single value; test if that goes good or bad and then debug from that.

Comment: So with the test table I'm getting an EOF error for everything but the -c option which gives an "invalid character value for cast specification" error but still copies the data. The EOF error is to do with the line ending characters but I wasn't getting this error when uploading to the actual table and both the test and actual csv files end in CR LF. Has this narrowed it down any? I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: You are using a CSV, but trying to import with a native format file. This cannot work. At least not the way you wrote your code. Export a format file for csv instead of native and try again

Comment: It looks like there may encoding issues. What is the encoding of your csv files? What is your client operating system? Can you post a link to the csv file you are trying to upload?

Comment: I have been using a format file but do I need to create the file differently for use with a csv and how would I do that? Would these problems be avoided if I used a tab delimited text file (I'll experiment with this today)? I can't share the csv file unfortunately as it has confidential data in it. Client operating system is Windows 10, the csv file is created by Excel through a VBscript. The encoding is ANSI. I'll try it with UTF-8. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: So I tried editing the format file to specify the column separators and row end but get the same errors. No difference between ANSI and UTF-8. I tired using a tab delimited txt file instead, this gave the same errors on the real table (Invalid date format) and gave no error on my test table (which just has the timestamp and one data column which is a float) but it didn't upload any of the data. It starts the copy and then exits saying 0 rows copied with no error messages. I should note the data in these files can be copy pasted into the tables with SSMS with no issue.

Comment: Can you test the following configuration? Remove the TimeStamp column from your csv file. Save your csv file as a Text (Tab delimited file) .txt file. Make sure that the encoding is Unicode Text. Upload the file to your instance of SQL Server using the bcp utility. Use the -w option and no format file. If this does not work, can you create a fake copy of your csv file so that we can replicate the issue ourselves and work out a solution.

Comment: Okay so using the -w option gives an EOF error with or without the timestamp column. Making a format file with -w gives an "incorrect host-column number in format file" error even though the format file, txt file and the database table all have 196 columns. I'll add a dummy version of my data to the main question as well as a dummy version of my table.

Comment: I downloaded your file. It's comma delimited. BCP default is tab delimited so you need to make sure you use options that specify comma delimited. Next thing to do is just change the data types of all the columns in your table to varchar(1000) and get the data into it and inspect it. It's normal to BCP into an all varchar staging table then transfer that into a table with proper data types

Comment: Yeah I had the proper options for comma delimited but I was getting the exact same errors with tab delimited. I'll try it with a staging table that's a good idea thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution thanks to Nick.McDermaid:

I created a staging table on the database with all the same column names as the destination table but with each column type as varchar.

Then bcp worked fine using the character option -c to upload into the staging table.

```
bcp dbo.Staging IN "output.csv" -S <URL> -d <databasename> -U <username> -P <password> -c -t ,
```

Then all it needs is the following SQL code to update the actual table and remove the data from the staging table.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Meters
SELECT * FROM dbo.Staging
GO

DELETE FROM dbo.Staging
GO
```